# s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, xjc, xml-validation, cxf-xjc-plugin

I am getting the below exception when validating unsignedInt in xsd. I am not able to validate the string 'abce' with unsignedInt type. 
Please help me regarding this.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="DistanceType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt">
            <enumeration value="4">
       </enumeration>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

In this restriction, i am the getting error for integer values also like 12,13.

```
**Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'The type is signed integer 16 bits'**
```

My Input:

```
 <type:Distance>123</type:Distance>
```

Final XSD:

```
<xsd:schema  targetNamespace="http://www.example.net/sample/ws/v1/extint/types" 
xmlns:extint="http://www.example.net/sample/ws/v1/extint/types" 
xmlns:types="http://www.example.net/sample/xsd/v1/types" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:import namespace="http://www.exanoke.net/sample/xsd/v1/types" schemaLocation="CommonTypes.xsd"/>

<xsd:element name="GetSomeRequest">

    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="types:SomeRequest">
                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="SearchDistance" type="types:DistanceType">

                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>


CommonTypes.xsd
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.net/example/xsd/v1/types"
    xmlns:types="http://www.example.net/sample/xsd/v1/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:simpleType name="DistanceType">

            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt">
                   <enumeration value="4">
                    </enumeration>
            </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

new One:

```
<xsd:schema  targetNamespace="http://www.example.net/sample/ws/v1/extint/types" 
xmlns:extint="http://www.example.net/sample/ws/v1/extint/types" 
xmlns:types="http://www.example.net/sample/xsd/v1/types" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.net/sample/xsd/v1/types" schemaLocation="CommonTypes.xsd"/>

<xsd:element name="GetBranchesRequest">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>INTF#09:
            Serach for a list of partner branch data in the vicinity of a given WGS 84
            position ordered
            by increasing distance. In case a member authentication is contained
            within the request the number of coupons available to the member
            within
            each branch is included within the result.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="types:InitialRequest">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Member" type="types:MemberType">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                Optional data used to identify and authenticate the
                                member
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Position" type="types:WGS84PositionType">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation> WGS 84 position determined by the
                                consumer
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Partner" type="types:PartnerContextType">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>Filter related to partner.
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="MatchLimit" type="types:MatchLimitType">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>Determines the upper limit of matches,
                                which are returned by ascending distance the
                                inter-face.
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="SearchDistance" type="types:DistanceType">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>The distance (measured in me-ters)
                                determines the perimeter based from the given
                                geo-location, where the system searches for branches.
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I am getting the same error for the string 'abcd' also.

Comment: for unsignedInt type, string validation is not happening.

Comment: For this restriction is only valid  `<type:Distance>4</type:Distance>` all the others value are wrong. What are you looking for?

Comment: If i passed elements like 'a' or any other special characters, It is not validating. it is allowing.

Comment: This is the sample input which is not working.  <typ:Distance>abcd</typ:Distance>

Comment: Very weird .. could you show us the entire XSD?

Comment: I have updated full xsd

Comment: your XSD are not valid. Can you provide us the correct XSDs?

Comment: Where is defined `types:InitialRequest` etc etc ?

Comment: Anyway .. as I said before, `<ns1:SearchDistance>4</ns1:SearchDistance>` for the `<xsd:simpleType name="DistanceType">` the only one possible value is 4.

Comment: but it is allowing alphabetic...that is my problem.

Comment: I suggest you to dowload [this software](http://www.donkeydevelopment.com/) to verify the consistency of your schema. See also [here a reference](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_numeric.asp) of `unsignedInt`. Anyway without all XSD involved is impossible to check this weird behaviour.